# Response from ASMX

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

We have an old bit of code, ASMX WebService, that we have lost the source to. I am trying to replicate the behavior of this so we can take control of it once again without affecting any of the clients.

I have created a class that mimics the behavior and properties of the response, and a soap request returns as follows

```
  <soap:Body>
<LoginResponse>
  <LoginResult>
    <UserId>string</UserId>
    <Password>string</Password>
  </LoginResult>
</LoginResponse>
```

Now the service I am trying to replicate returns

```
    <soap:Body>
    <LoginRS xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <UserId>string</UserId>
        <Password>Password</Password>
    </LoginRS>
</soap:Body>
```

Now LoginRS is the name of the class I have made. My question is how do I make my response look like the second response.

I am replicating this in c# ASMX and am using the following

```
    [WebMethod(MessageName="Login")]
    public LoginRS Login(string password, string userId)
```

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Since you are showing the soap message I am presuming you have access to the compiled source?  I recommend just decompiling the assembly and getting the correct source code.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to reverse engineer the service, and if the service dll is with you, you can use .NET Reflector (google it) to read the dll and provide you the exact source code.